# Background Image out of proportion in xamarin.forms IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I've created an app using xamarin.forms. I just began testing the iOS side and my background image on the login screen looks zoomed in. On android the image displays correctly. Is there anything I need to change to get it to display correctly?

**Mainpage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.MainPage"
             BackgroundImage="bk3.jpg"
            >
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <!-- top controls -->
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <!-- middle controls -->
            <BoxView HeightRequest="430"></BoxView>
            <Button Text="Continue with Facebook" x:Name="LoginBtn" BackgroundColor="#4867aa" TextColor="White" FontFamily="Klavika" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="LoginBtn_Clicked" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <!-- bottom controls -->
            <Frame OutlineColor="White" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <!-- bottom controls -->
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
                        <Label  
                               Text="Terms and conditions"
                              FontSize="13"
                            TextColor="#71757a"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            x:Name="LblTerms"/>
                        <Label  
                            Text=" and"
                            FontSize="13"
                            TextColor="#71757a"
                            />

                        <Label  
                               Text=" privacy policy"
                            FontSize="13"
                            TextColor="#71757a"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            x:Name="LblPrivacy"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Screenshots in both iOS and Android.**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this all in 1 background image? except facebook signin button and other bottom button

Comment: yep its a background image. I just added the button for Facebook and the terms and conditions at the bottom on it

Comment: I dnt think you can play much with content page background image, i suggest to go with relative layout and image for background, if ou need i can post some sample code here

Comment: Ah i see, yes please I'd appreciate sample code. Thanks

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.MainPage" >
  <RelativeLayout>
    <Image Source="bk3.jpg" 
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>
      <PUT YOUR REST OF CODE HERE>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage>

Comment: Copy this code to new page and first check its work correctly on both android and ios, then put rest of the code

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked :)

Comment: i have post it as answer, you can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not play much on ContentPage Background image in In IOS its not picking up correctly. i will propose 2 solutions for you to get rid of this situation...

try both and get what matched to you

Solution 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.MainPage" >
  <RelativeLayout>
    <Image Source="bk3.jpg" 
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>

                  <PUT YOUR REST OF CODE HERE>

  </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Solution 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" >
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.MainPage"
             Padding="0">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="bk3.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" />
        <StackLayout>

        <PUT YOUR REST OF CODE HERE>

        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Update me with which suites you best....

Comment: Hi Shiwanka, Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47387836/background-image-for-grid-in-xamarin-forms . I tried your solution on my gridView also for background image but to no avail. Appreciate if you can help, thanks