# Background Image for grid in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set a background image for my entire grid, not just for a single row/column. Setting `BackgroundImage= "image.jpg"` works on android but on iOS it appears stretched. I've attached a screenshot from the android side to be more clear of how it should be.

[image]

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.GridMenu"
             Title="Main Menu"
             >

    <Grid>
        <Image Source="grid.jpg"></Image>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Text="Cards" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#1481BA"  Opacity="0.5" x:Name="CardTile"/>
        <Label Text="Transactions" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#ede890" Opacity="0.5" x:Name="TransactionTile"/>
        <Label Text="Promotions" TextColor="White" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#1481BA" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0.7" x:Name="PromoTile"/>
        <Label Text="Settings" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#ede890" Opacity="0.5" x:Name="SettingsTile" />
        <Label Text="My Profile" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#1481BA" Opacity="0.7" x:Name="ProfileTile"/>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

As you can see in the above code I've tried to add  but all this does is include the image on the "Cards" block. How can I set it behind the entire grid?

[image]

Comment: How about adding Image tag to these properties <Image Source="grid.jpg" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"/>   to fit to the grid size?

Comment: Tried it, still displays the image only on the cards section of the grid

Comment: see my edit for the iOS screenshot. That's what it is currently doing. I need the image to cover the whole page as a background

Comment: You got good answer, try that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options here.

### The `Image` within the `Grid`

The first option is very close to what you tried: Placing the background image in the `Grid`.

Please note that XAML is declarative and not sequential. Just because you've placed the `Grid.RowDefinitions` and the `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` after the `Image` this does not mean that they don't apply to it.

You will still have to set `Grid.RowSpan="3"` and `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` in the `Image` tag.

This will work as long as there is no `Padding` in the `Grid`. If you define the `Grid` with a `Padding` greater zero the `Image` will not stretch to the whole parent view, but only the region within the padding. This leads us to the second option: Absolute layout.

### Using an `AbsoluteLayout`

With an `AbsoluteLayout` (see the docs [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/)) you are (to some extent) a bit more flexible (but it comes with its own quirks). Basically you are wrapping the `Grid` in an `AbsoluteLayout` and place the `Image` behind the `Grid`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.GridMenu"
             Title="Main Menu">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Source="grid.jpg" />
        <Grid AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" >
            <!-- Elided -->
        </Grid>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```